# What is the grammars of this sentence "Think of a person you consider to be successful."

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the grammars of this sentence "Think of a person you consider to be successful."

The grammar has caused I don't understand meaning.

Comment: What part of it can you not make sense of? It it the order of the words?

Comment: Think of = consider

Comment: There aren't any conjunction between Think of a person and you consider.....

Comment: "Think of" can mean "mentally find an example of".

Answer (score 1):

Often the conjunction (actually a *relative pronoun*) is understood and left out. This has the same meaning as *think of a person ***that*** you consider to be successful* or *think of a person ***whom*** you consider to be successful.*

This is very common, especially in short sentences:

> I'm not the man *[that, whom]* I used to be.
> That's the dog *[that]* I saw running loose earlier.
> That hill *[that]* I climbed yesterday wore me out.

I put that last one in there to remind you that *that* has two different meanings. (Did you get all that? :) )

[This](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/subordinating-conjunctions.html) is a basic explanation of the difference between conjunctions and relative pronouns. (You'll also want to understand the difference between coordinating and subordinating conjunctions.)

Answer (score 1):

> [Think of a person] **(A)** [you consider to be successful] **(B)**.

(A) is the main clause of this sentence, whereas (B) is a relative clause modifying the noun ***person*** and answers the question "which kind of person?".

The complete sentence would be:

> (A) (***that/whom*** B). (where "that/whom" introduce the relative clause)

However, as the other answer indicated, *relative pronouns* like "that, whom, who, which" are commonly left out but everyone understands that they are there in meaning. Here is what this [Learning English site](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/defining-relative-clauses/#:%7E:text=The%20relative%20pronoun%20can%20only,followed%20by%20another%20subject%20%2B%20verb.) says about the subject:

> The relative pronoun ***can only be omitted when it is the object of the clause***. When the relative pronoun is the subject of the clause, it cannot be omitted. You can usually tell when a relative pronoun is the object of the clause because it is followed by another subject + verb.
>
> - e.g. 1. The woman   ***that***  spoke at the meeting    was very knowledgeable.
> - 2. The woman    *(that/whom)*   the man loved   was living in New York.

Note that if the relative pronoun is neither the object nor the subject of the relative clause, but is preceded by a preposition, again, it cannot be omitted:

> - [Think of a person] [***for whom*** you have sacrificed a lot].
> - [Think of a task] [***on which*** you don't want to waste too much time].

Comment: A lot thanks for your questions.